# iPhone: How to gather Credit Card information upon swiping with device attached to it?

Tags: iphone, credit-card, swipe, smartcard-reader

I want to add credit card swipe feature to my application. 
What do I need to make it work?
All I need is 
1. Swipe the card
2. Populate the fields on the view with the card info
3. Store that populated into database(I have an idea in this db part), which will be used for further process later.
 Please help me how to start programming for this. I have card reader device. What do I need to do?

Comment: Which device is it? Does it come with a SDK?

Comment: It is ID TECH's UniMag magnetic stripe reader.

Answer (score 2):

The device comes with the SDK and Full documentation. You just run the sample application that comes with SDK. If its working correctly, u can integrate the same in ur project. My device came with 2.7 SDK but that did not work for me, then I upgraded to 3.3 SDK.

3.3 SDK version working fine for me.

Comment: I am working on the same iMag card reader. How did you get it running? I mean in my case it's unable to locate the IDTech framework, though, it's added in the project. Giving me list of errors!!!